# Tee user responses to prompts

Tags: linux, tee

Is it possible to have tee emit responses to prompts?

That is, I run a program (e.g. *openssl req*) that prompts for user inputs, and run it through tee to produce a log. tee emits the prompts produced by the program, but *not* the user's responses.

```
openssl req *some options* | tee -a openssl-req.log
```

The user sees

> Generating a RSA private key
> *snip*
> Country Name [US]:FA
> State or Province Name [CA]:
> snip*

but openssl-req.log contains

> Generating a RSA private key
> *snip*
> Country Name [US]:State or Province Name [CA]:City or other
> *snip*

The user responses, including line-breaks, are not present in tee's output.

Comment: See the [script utility - Save all the terminal output to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200637/save-all-the-terminal-output-to-a-file) (not perfect, but does what you need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D. Rankin's suggestion works. A little trickery gets the full output, including the command:

`script -q  -a` *logfile* `-c "(set -x ;`*command*`)"`